# Fluid mechanic derive [4.5-4.9] and [4.8-.11]

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Hye, this is my first time to ask in this group. I am not familiar with fluid mechanics and currently self-learning for postgraduate study and facing difficulties in deriving both 4.9 and 4.11 as below.

for 4.5, I understand it is PDE, but I do not know how they extract porosity and density and differentiate only pressure.

for 4.8, it is simple to integrate, and I managed to bring dp(pressure) to left-hand side (LHS) and by integrate from $p_0$ to $p$, it will give the value as 4.11. However, I do not know where the $\rho$(density) which is p0 came from. I think by integrating $d\ln(\rho)$ which is density it should give initial value $\ln(\rho)$?

Sorry for my bad knowledge, I am trying to refresh my math skills and I do not have a background in fluid mechanics which is crucial for my postgraduate study.

[image: derive4.5-4.9 and 4.8-4.11]

Comment: $$\frac{d \ln \rho}{dp} = c_{f} \implies \int \frac{d \ln \rho}{dp} dp = \int c_{f} dp \implies \ln \rho = c_{f} p + C \implies \rho = C e^{c_{f} p}$$ and the condition that a pressure datum $p_{0}$ yields a known density $\rho_{0}$ implies $\rho(p_{0}) = Ce^{c_{f} p_{0}} = \rho_{0} \implies C = \rho_{0} e^{-c_{f} p_{0}}$